# IAR Embedded Workbench menu bar missing

Tags: arm, embedded, iar

I have IAR Embedded Workbench - ARM 8.20.2 in a production environment and it looks like someone hit something causing the menu bar to be hidden. There are no obvious hamburger menus, dropdowns, etc that I can click on to easily get it back, just a blank barren menu area without a contextual (right click) menu. just above the usual IAR tool bar. I would normally look at the IAR key bindings to figure this out, but.. there's no menu and can't find a shortcut for that. I've spent awhile now googling this without any luck. Does anyone out there know if there is a shortcut for toggling the menu bar?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Are the toolbars visible? If they are, you could try to click the down arrow at the right end of one, and then go to `Add or Remove Buttons > Customize... > Toolbars` and make sure that `Menu Bar` is not unset, and reset it if possible. You shouldn't even be able to disable that setting, so I don't even know why it is there available.

Comment: Thanks @user694733, I looked at that and sure enough the menu bar is diabled, but... I can't reenable it it just does nothing when I click it... Tried resetting and still disabled. Oddly, when I first start IAR up it shows the menu bar, but when it finishes loading the last workspace it goes away. I tried opening up other workspaces, but it's still missing and can't be enabled once the workspace finishes loading. Now obviously I could try reinstalling, but I really need to get at the settings in this one to troubleshoot another system that's giving me issues.

Comment: This is not really a suitable question for SO I think - better ask IAR support or community forum.  I am not a user of IAR, but it sounds like some local setting associated with the project Apart from the project file are there any other generated files associated with the project?  Keil uVision for example keeps local settings in a .uvopts file and often deleting that can resolve UI issues - if IAR has a similar file I advise against checking it is as part of the project, because it contains local settings an preferences specifioc to a particular user.

Comment: Although invisible, they can be accessed from the keyboard by pressing <ALT> and then T or F (be sure to release <ALT> before pressing the next key). To move between the menus, use the arrow keys in the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting the PROJECT_NAME.wsdt file from the settings folder in the projects. Thank you to both @user694733 and @Clifford for their help with this.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the menu bar missing applied to all projects in a workspace. To fix it, exited IAR workbench, and deleted the .wsdt file in the workspace folder. Then restarted IARWorkbench and loaded the workspace file. I found that the workspace was reset  for all projects in that workspace, and the menu bar was present as expected. Problem solved. Thanks for the previous post about the .wsdt file.

Answer (score 0):

The file Project.wsdt resides in a directory called "settings".
If deleting only the file doesn't help, close the software, delete the entire directory (or rename it, to be on the safe side), and then open the project again.